# How to sum values stacked in different Rows? PHP PDO MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum, fetch

Let's say we have a very simple while row query script, for example:

```
<?php 
include('conection.php');

    $Verd = 'Verduras';
    $smt = $con->prepare("select * from prodcts WHERE Type = :Verduras Order by PrdName ASC");
    $smt->bindParam(':Verduras', $Verd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $smt->execute();
while ($smr = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) 
        {
        echo '<th>'.nl2br($smr['PrdName']).'</th><th>'.nl2br($smr['SellType']).'</th><th>$'.nl2br($smr['Cost']).'</th>';
        }
?>
```

Question:

How can i make than the results of the `$smr['Cost']` Sum it up with the `$smr['Cost']` of the rest/some others rows?

Any commentary, suggestion, question for improve the question or any kind of related answer looking to help & improve the question or result in the solution, etc would be much apreciated

Thanks in Advance!

PS: i check for another answers before, but mostly was mysql oriented, nevertheless i wanna check for a PHP more oriented solution, so to have more control about it and try to avoid (if possible) multiple querys.

Comment: You can make use of MySQL's aggregate `COUNT()` and `SUM()` functions. PHP also has a `count()` function.

Comment: So, is there no way to actualy avoid using a second table to store the rows you want in and then sum them up?

Comment: I don't get the point. Could you please post some sample of raw data, and expected result ?

Comment: I edited my comment above; saying that PHP also has a `count()` function. You can also use mathematical operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wasn't expecting all this solutions all this fast, i'll be checking it all of them later, than again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the while loop, create a variable. In the while loop increase the variable by the value you want to add. 
e.g:

```
$total = 0;
while ($smr = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) 
{
echo '<th>'.nl2br($smr['PrdName']).'</th>
  <th>'.nl2br($smr['SellType']).'</th>
  <th>$'.nl2br($smr['Cost']).'</th>';
$total += $smr['Cost'];
}
```

At the end, when you call `$total`, it will contain the sum.

```
<?php echo $total ?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wasn't expecting all this solutions all this fast, i'll be checking it all of them later, than again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you need the sum of all rows, you can just create a variable before the while...

```
$Verd = 'Verduras';
$sum = 0;
$smt = $con->prepare("select * from prodcts WHERE Type = :Verduras Order by PrdName ASC");
$smt->bindParam(':Verduras', $Verd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$smt->execute();
while ($smr = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
    echo '<th>'.nl2br($smr['PrdName']).'</th><th>'.nl2br($smr['SellType']).'</th><th>$'.nl2br($smr['Cost']).'</th>';
    $sum += $smr['Cost'];
}
echo $sum;
```

But if you need the value grouped $smr['PrdName'], just create a new array..

```
$Verd = 'Verduras';
$sum = 0;
$smt = $con->prepare("select * from prodcts WHERE Type = :Verduras Order by PrdName ASC");
$smt->bindParam(':Verduras', $Verd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$smt->execute();
while ($smr = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
  $prd[$smr['PrdName']][$smr['SellType']][0] += $smr['Cost'];
}
```

After that, you can display each line with a foreach...
It's easily to control using only SQL, but if you need to realize the treatment with PHP, i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wasn't expecting all this solutions all this fast, i'll be checking it all of them later, than again, thanks a lot